# What does "since I lived /was/ have been in London" mean in different contexts

Tags: grammar

What does *"since I lived /was/ have been in London"* mean in different contexts? According to my research, I've now come to these conclusions. Would you please check whether they're correct or not?

I:

> It's been 5 years since I lived in London.

> It's been 5 years since I was in London.

> It's been 5 years since I've been in London.

all mean that It's been 5 years since I left London.

II:

> I've exercised regularly since I lived in London.

> I've exercised regularly since I was in London

both mean I started to exercise regularly at some point when I was in London. Later I left London. Now I'm not in London. But I've exercised regularly since that point when I was in London.

III:

> I've exercised regularly since I've been in London.

means that I'm in London now. I might have moved here, or I might have come here for a short stay, say, a three-month business trip. Either situation, I've exercised regularly since I  arrived in London.

Comment: Yes, I'd say they are correct, but I: ii and iii could also refer to visits to London.

Comment: "It's been 5 years since I've been in London." the two 'beens' make this awkward. The first one can be removed.

Comment: All are correct to me except "It's been 5 years since I've been in London." This sentence is unnatural and, without context, hard to interpret. When you say "since I've been in London," it implies to me that you're still there, which is why your final example makes sense. So if I heard this example and tried to make sense of it without context, I might hear it as: "It's been five years that I've been in London," which is a wordy way of saying "I've been in London for five years." Or I might interpret it the way you suggest. I don't know. I'm in the U.S. and can speak only for my people.

Comment: "Lived in London" means was resident there, i.e., had a home there and (may have) spent a long time there. "Was in London" and "been in London" suggest a visit to London, perhaps just a day trip or a few days in a hotel. The "was in" and "been" forms suggest a short duration but they could also be used by someone who "lived" there.